# What is the best Azure service for running a .net core 3.1 console app on a schedule?

Tags: azure, .net, dotnet-framework

I have a .Net Core 3.1 console application that runs on a schedule (currently hosted on a VM).  It gets some settings from it's config file and uses http to grab data from an API and feed it into a SQL database (connection string etc. is in it's config file).  It also logs various output to a text file.

I need to lift and shift it to the Azure environment (VPS is not an option).  What is the best service for this given that it needs to be scheduled to run every day at 10pm?  Should I create a web app, a function, a service bus?  I preferably don't want to fiddle with the app code too much.

I have read documentation for these services but am still a bit confused about which is the best fit and why.
Thanks!

Comment: how long does it run for?

Comment: Probably 4 hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Function supports this by the looks. Functions are cheap and lightweight. Trigger the app based on a timer. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/serverless/azure-functions